# Scaling and snapping problems

Tags: transforms, snapping

I want to scale my object so that the red points line up with the blue points. I tried snapping and moving the left points together and then scaling the right red point to the right blue point, but it didn't snap to the blue point. I hope that makes sense. I just want to have the red points line up to the blue points while the object is scaled proportionately on all axis.

[image]

Comment: Are these points vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with snapping. Here are the steps:

1. Snapping should be set to *Vertex*, snap with *Active*, and affect *Move* and *Scale*.
2. Select one of the red vertices, and run *Select > Select Linked > Linked* to select the linked geometry. If the geometry is not linked, manually select the pieces making sure the active vertex is the first red vertex.
3. Move the selected geometry placing the mouse cursor over the first blue vertex.
4. Run *Mesh > Snap > Cursor to Active* to place the 3D cursor at the first red vertex (which overlaps the first blue vertex now).
5. Switch the *Transform Pivot Point* to use the *3D Cursor*.
6. Select the second red vertex, and run *Select > Select Linked > Linked* to select the linked geometry. As mentioned above, if the geometry is not linked, manually select the pieces making sure the active vertex is the second red vertex.
7. Scale the selected geometry placing the mouse cursor over the second blue vertex.

A GIF is attached below showing the steps.

[image: Steps]